# Error in exporting list of dictionaries to csv

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary, web-scraping

I'm trying to export a list of dictionaries to excel, such that the csv file will have one column per variable, with all the keys' corresponding values.

I've tried trying to export a dictionary of dictionaries instead, and a list of lists with a dictionary each, but none of them appear to work. What should I do?

```py
url_test = 'http://app.parlamento.pt/webutils/docs/doc.txt?path=6148523063446f764c324679626d56304c3239775a57356b595852684c3052685a47397a51574a6c636e5276637939535a576470633352764a544977516d6c765a334c446f575a705932387657456c4a535355794d45786c5a326c7a6247463064584a684c314a6c5a326c7a644739436157396e636d466d61574e7657456c4a53563971633239754c6e523464413d3d&fich=RegistoBiograficoXIII_json.txt&Inline=true'

r_test = requests.get(url_test)

mps = cont['RegistoBiografico']['RegistoBiograficoList']['pt_ar_wsgode_objectos_DadosRegistoBiograficoWeb']

result = {}

for j in mps:
     ID = j['cadId']
     Nome = j['cadNomeCompleto']
     Sexo = j['cadSexo']
     resultf = {'ID':ID, 'Nome':Nome, 'Sexo':Sexo}
     result.append(resultf)

with open('bio_json.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    writer = DictWriter(outfile, ('ID', 'Nome', 'Sexo', 'Profissao', 'Legislatura'))
    writer.writerows(result)
```

I would expect a final csv as described above. However, after `writer.writerows(result)`, i get this message:

```
File "C:\Users\fnac\Desktop\Universidade do Minho\Software\lib\csv.py", line 158, in writerows
    return self.writer.writerows(map(self._dict_to_list, rowdicts))
  File "C:\Users\fnac\Desktop\Universidade do Minho\Software\lib\csv.py", line 148, in _dict_to_list
    wrong_fields = rowdict.keys() - self.fieldnames
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Comment: Your code, as listed, can't work even before that line – `result` is declared a dict (`{}`), not a list, and you're attempting to use the list method `.append()` on it.

Comment: (Not to mention `cont` isn't defined, etc.)

Comment: Hi. Yeah, I copied the code I'd already written in a very sloppy way. Glad you understood what I intended anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list of dicts works fine:

```py
import requests
import csv

resp = requests.get(
    "http://app.parlamento.pt/webutils/docs/doc.txt?path=6148523063446f764c324679626d56304c3239775a57356b595852684c3052685a47397a51574a6c636e5276637939535a576470633352764a544977516d6c765a334c446f575a705932387657456c4a535355794d45786c5a326c7a6247463064584a684c314a6c5a326c7a644739436157396e636d466d61574e7657456c4a53563971633239754c6e523464413d3d&fich=RegistoBiograficoXIII_json.txt&Inline=true"
)
resp.raise_for_status()
data = resp.json()

mps = data["RegistoBiografico"]["RegistoBiograficoList"]["pt_ar_wsgode_objectos_DadosRegistoBiograficoWeb"]

result = [
    {
        "ID": j["cadId"],
        "Nome": j["cadNomeCompleto"],
        "Sexo": j["cadSexo"],
    }
    for j in mps
]

with open("bio_json.csv", "w") as outfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(
        outfile,
        ("ID", "Nome", "Sexo", "Profissao", "Legislatura"),
    )
    writer.writerows(result)
```

`bio_json.csv` looks like

```
2167,ABEL LIMA BAPTISTA,M,,
3,ADÃO JOSÉ FONSECA SILVA,M,,
462,ALBERTO DE SOUSA MARTINS,M,,
...
```

Comment: This helped a lot. Thank you! But if I want to loop through all of the JSONs (I've created a list with around 30 of them), I'll need the the result list inside the for loop, right?

Comment: So making about 20 requests, etc, and ending up with one CSV? I'd wrap the bits that create the `result` array here in a function accepting the original `url`, then call that for each URL... I can augment my answer for that if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a dataframe from a list of dictionaries quite easily and write to file (nice job AKX on list comprehension in his solution).

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

resp = requests.get(
    "http://app.parlamento.pt/webutils/docs/doc.txt?path=6148523063446f764c324679626d56304c3239775a57356b595852684c3052685a47397a51574a6c636e5276637939535a576470633352764a544977516d6c765a334c446f575a705932387657456c4a535355794d45786c5a326c7a6247463064584a684c314a6c5a326c7a644739436157396e636d466d61574e7657456c4a53563971633239754c6e523464413d3d&fich=RegistoBiograficoXIII_json.txt&Inline=true"
)
resp.raise_for_status()
data = resp.json()

mps = data["RegistoBiografico"]["RegistoBiograficoList"]["pt_ar_wsgode_objectos_DadosRegistoBiograficoWeb"]

result = [
    {
        "ID": j["cadId"],
        "Nome": j["cadNomeCompleto"],
        "Sexo": j["cadSexo"],
        "Profissao": "", 
        "Legislatura": ""
    }
    for j in mps
]

df = pd.DataFrame(result)
df.to_csv('bio_json.csv')
```

Or in just one line:

```
pd.DataFrame(result).to_csv('bio_json.csv')
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your help. I've heard of that package before, but didn't know how to use it. Why are some of the names not appearing in the output file as they are supposed to? E.g., 1,3,ADÃƒO JOSÃ‰ FONSECA SILVA,M instead of 1,3,ADÃO JOSÉ FONSECA SILVA,M